# can I debug an execution that starts in gradle task?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

I'm using intellij as IDEA

and I want to run a gradle task and debug the code exection afterwards.

Is that possible somehow?
If so - how?

Comment: Unclear; do you want to debug the task itself?

Comment: say I want to run tests with specific injected system property. I want to verify the properties were injected while code runs.